# Probability of getting a higher value from a normal distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

You have two **independent** random variables $X$ and $Y$ each of a zero mean, unit variance distribution. What is the $P(X>5Y)$?

Comment: What have you tried? How I would start, is that I would combine them into a new random variable $Z= X-5Y$.

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent? If yes, how is $Z$ distributed?

Comment: @callculus yes they are independent.

Comment: @Mellow First  of all you have to answer two questions: What is $\mathbb E(X-5Y)=...$ and $Var(X-5Y)$, if X and Y are independent. The independency does not affect the expected value but the variance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps surprisingly, the answer is $1/2$.  Aside from callculus's approach, there is a short-circuit-y way to see the same thing.  For any given values $X$ and $Y$, we can observe that $X > 5Y$ if and only if $-X < 5(-Y)$.  By symmetry*, then, the probability is $1/2$.

*We have to be careful here, because $X$ and $-X$ have to be "equally likely" (in a way that can be made precise), as well as $Y$ and $-Y$.  Fortunately, that happens to hold in this case.

---

Here is a pictorial representation of the situation.  The red line is $X = 5Y$, and the blue blur is a schematic depiction of the normal bivariate ordered pair $(X, Y)$.  How much of that blur is below the line, where $X > 5Y$?  How much of it is above the line, where $X < 5Y$?

[image]

Hopefully, this makes things more intuitively satisfying.  Note that the graphical approach allows you to answer such questions as what the probability is if we require $Y > 0$.  In that case, we restrict ourselves to the upper half-plane, and since the bivariate normal distribution is radially symmetric, we see that the probability is just $\frac{\arctan 1/5}{\pi} \approx 0.062833$.  (Oddly, this is very close to, but not equal to, $\pi/50$.)

---

Finally, some quick code:

```
import random

length = 1000000

random.seed()

tally = 0
for i in range(length):
    x = random.gauss(0, 1)
    y = random.gauss(0, 1)
    # while y < 0:
    #     y = random.gauss(0, 1)
    if (x > 5*y):
        tally += 1

print(float(tally)/length)
```

The code that is commented out forces `y` to be positive.  If we leave it commented out, we get

```
% python normal.py
0.500236
```

If we put the code back in, we get

```
% python normal.py
0.062806
```

Just a couple of data points.

Comment: Thanks. I get it now.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some hints to answer the question:

1. $\mathbb E(Z)=\mathbb E(X-b\cdot Y)=\mathbb E(X)-b\cdot \mathbb  E(Y)$
2. The linear combination of two (or more) normally distributed variables is normally distributed as well.
3. In this case we don´t need to know the variance of $Z$. We can use the property of symmetry of the normal distribution.

Comment: So E(Z) is zero and you said that the variance doesn't matter. So I'm confused about what I'm supposed to do

Comment: @Mellow Yes, $\mathbb E(Z)$ is zero and Z is symmetric distributed around $0$. Thus $P(Z>0)=P(Z<0)=...$

Comment: Are you saying that the answer is 0.5? That doesn't sound right

Comment: @Mellow: Oh yes, indeed.  Unless you make some restriction such as $Y > 0$.

Comment: @Mellow " *Are you saying that the answer is 0.5* ? That doesn't sound right" But it is right if you take into account the items 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: @Mellow simulate in Excel

Comment: @Mellow If something is still unclear feel to ask. This [link](https://www.statlect.com/probability-distributions/normal-distribution-linear-combinations) maybe helps.

Comment: @BrianTung I am so confused right now. Is the answer 0.5 no matter the value of $b$. Shouldn't higher values of $b$ give a smaller probability?

Comment: @Mellow: No, it should be $1/2$ no matter what.  Take a look at the diagram in my answer.  It should be intuitively clear that no matter how we rotate the red line around the origin, it cuts the bivariate distribution into two identical pieces, each with the same measure.